# Как получать и складывать значения data из мультиселекта?

Tags: javascript

Есть мультиселект. Нужно при изменении селекта получать data у выбранных option и складывать их. Или вычитать если их убрали.
У меня получилось только получать data первого option. Видимо нужно обходить выбранные, но не хватает знаний JS что бы понять как.

```js
  let add=0;
  jQuery(".js-example-basic-multiple2").on("change", function () {
        
        add += +jQuery(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-price');
        
        
        summ();
    });
    
    function summ() {
      $('p').text(add);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple2" name="add-programm[]" multiple="multiple">
<option data-price="0" value="0"></option>
    <option data-price="1" value="1С:ЭДО">Программа1</option>
    <option data-price="2" value="1С:Контрагент">Программа2</option>
    <option data-price="3" value="1С-ОФД">Программа3</option>
    </select>
    
    <p>0</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let add = 0;
jQuery(".js-example-basic-multiple2").on("change", function() {
  add = 0;
  jQuery(this).find('option:selected').each(function(){
    add += +$(this).data('price');
  });
  summ();
});

function summ() {
  $('p').text(add);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple2" name="add-programm[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option data-price="0" value="0"></option>
  <option data-price="1" value="1С:ЭДО">Программа1</option>
  <option data-price="2" value="1С:Контрагент">Программа2</option>
  <option data-price="3" value="1С-ОФД">Программа3</option>
</select>

<p>0</p>
```